# When does Sitecore create a profile record in Profiles table of Analytic database

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms

I create demo pages. In the main page it will display preferred item based on number which has biggest number of clicks on the listing page. I can do it with personalization of Sitecore. But I have some issues with user profiles.

I created an user, did login, and then click on an item for serveral times. The main page can show that preferred item. I did logout ( I clear two session cookies SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE and SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE), and then login again. What I want here is to show that preferred item again. But it can't. (1)

I set SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE and SC_ANALYTICS_SESSION_COOKIE as the correct id of profile of that user. But it didn't show the preferred item. I think when I set correct values of these two session cookies, it can load correct profile of registered user. Is my approach wrong?

I checked database and found that there are several profile records which are related to that userid. I think it should be 1 - 1 relation. When does Sitecore create a new profile record?

Beside, is there any suggestion for my request (1)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What Sitecore version is used?

Comment: I have deleted all records in all tables of Analysis database, then I navigated to my main page. The data is still displayed with personalization. I think somewhere else saved this information. It is not related to Profiles table.